# Styles on Material-UI: Undefined CSS fields

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add this `CSS` class to an element from **Material-UI**:

```css
bw:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Could be done using `makeStyles`:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  bw: {
      filter: grayscale('100%'),
  },
});
```

But this is not working because **`grayscale` is undefined**.

I really do not see any advantages on this style of styling with `makeStyles` and all other classes from **Material-UI**: you do not only have to change the syntax to adapt it to JavaScript syntax there are also some properties do not exist! wtf!

Well, enough bashing, so I though, just override the component style:

And so, I went to the docs of this component: [CardMedia](https://material-ui.com/api/card-media/) from Material-UI, according to it I should be able to override the css class of the image tag:`.MuiCardMedia-img`, so I tryied to override it directly on the .css file of the app but again it just does not work:

```cs
.MuiCardMedia-img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Maybe I did not understand something, I'll appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the css of any material component will be like this

```
const style = {
  newMedia: {
    //css property
  }
}

<CardMedia classes={{media: classes.newMedia}} />
```

I added this link below, Please check and update if this will work for you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-rubin-4viw0

Comment: Still, I'm unable to apply the effect over the img, because it is a background I guess, where should I apply it?

Comment: I edited my answer, please check link mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to change it as a `string` in `makeStyles` just like the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  bw: {
    filter: `grayscale('100%')`,
  },
});
```

In your case, it is looking for a function called `grayscale` which is not existing in your code. It is just a `CSS` property and that's how you pass to `makeStlyles`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, still this effect is not applying to the img, why and how to achive it?